# Cannot find type definition file for 'moment'. The file is in the program because: Entry point for implicit type library 'moment'ts

Tags: node-modules, angular-moment, tsconfig.json

A brief background of what brought me here:

1. I formatted the operating system disk.
2. Reinstalled Windows 10 on my computer.
3. Installed node/npm through NVM in the version previously used in my project (12.8.0).
4. Cloned my project from the GitHub repository.
5. I ran the npm install command to install the packages.
6. Opened the project in Visual Studio Code.

[Then this error appeared in the tsconfig.json file:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2i3U.png)

Cannot find type definition file for 'moment'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'moment'ts
JSON schema for the TypeScript compiler's configuration file

My tsconfig.json code:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@abp/*": [ "../node_modules/abp-ng2-module/dist/src/*" ],
      "@app/*": [ "./app/*" ],
      "@shared/*": [ "./shared/*" ],
      "@node_modules/*": [ "../node_modules/*" ],
      "@moment/*": [ "../node_modules/moment/*" ]
    }
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I found two folders in different locations for the **moment **package, containing the following files:

[Under "..\node_modules\moment"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tGnE.png)

[Under "..\node_modules@types\moment"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKt7r.png)

Despite the error presented, the project apparently works with "npm run hmr" command, rendering in the web browser and connecting to the backend.

I have tried the solutions presented in similar problems, but without success.

I hope to be able to run the project again without this very annoying error warning. Any help is welcome. Thank you.